# Kotin application won't stop when using fixedRateTimer (even when window is closed)

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have a simple app in Kotlin that draws a rectangle and then uses a fixedRateTimer to update the location of the rectangle 30 times a second. The problem I have is that when I close the window displaying the rectangle the application keeps running and I have to press the red square inside Intellij to actually stop it.

I have tried cancelling the fixedRateTimer before I close the window but the application is still running it just doesn't seem to do anything. If I run the application without the fixedRateTimer it just displays the square and then when I close the window it stops the application.

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color
import tornadofx.*
import kotlin.concurrent.fixedRateTimer

class MyApp: App(MyView::class)

class MyView : View() {

    override val root = stackpane {
        group {
            rectangle {
                fill = Color.LIGHTGRAY
                width = 600.0
                height = 480.0
            }

            val myRect = rectangle {
                fill = Color.BLUEVIOLET
                width = 30.0
                height = 30.0
                x = 100.0
                y = 100.0
            }

            fixedRateTimer("default", false, 0L, 1000/30) {
                myRect.x += 1
                if(myRect.x > 200) this.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are cancelling your TimerTask, but not the timer. Either pass `daemon = true` to make a daemon thread, or make sure you save the `Timer` instance returned from the `fixedRateTimer()` call, and at some point call `cancel` on it to stop the non-daemon thread from running the timer before you exit.

The JVM will exit when there are daemon threads running, but not when there are non-daemon threads.

Comment: `fixedRateTimer()` runs on which coroutine?

Comment: I swear, I've saved all possible references (yeah just that one) of those Timers, calling cancel, purge, setting it null. It's running and running, in my case even (as user switches happen) multiple more and more instances. Hell No! That's crap.